# Mongoose failing to validate array properties

Tags: validation, node.js, mongoose

I'm having some issues with validating an array property in Mongoose.

When I use the following definition, my `shouldFail` method never gets called, and the record always saves.

```
shouldFail = (val) ->
  console.log "Fail method called with value:"
  console.log val
  return false

definitions:
  english: [
    type: String
    validate: [ shouldFail, "testing" ]
    required: true
  ]
```

However if I set up validation as the following, the function gets called and the record is not saved.

```
Sense.path('definitions.english').validate (val) ->
  console.log "Validating English"
  console.log val
  return false
```

I'd prefer to use the former definition style if possible. I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong in my definition. Is that how you define validation for arrays?

Also I'm not sure if the way I'm setting `english` is affecting this. I'm just doing `definitions.english = [ ]` and trying to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the [] on english:, fiddling with the code on the coffeescript compiler it renders out way wrong if you include them. That is likely why your validation isn't working in that format. Try just:

```
definitions:
  english:
    type: String
    validate: [ shouldFail, "testing" ]
    required: true
```

Comment: You're right. The Coffeescript is coming out different to how I expected. I'm still a little confused about the definition of array properties in Mongoose. I'll edit my question as there's not much room here for formatting.

Comment: Wait I think I get it now. I need the Array mark around the Type. So my definition will be the same except for `type: [String]`... I think.

Comment: If I were defining it in JS I'd do `definitions: ({ english: {type: String, validate: [shouldFail, 'testing'], required: true}})` so however you get that sort of output via coffeescript is the way to go (which I think is removing the [] on english: and using indentions instead so it defines it as an object and not an array.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the question and chosen answer are quite old, but I think it may still be useful to elaborate a bit more.

It seems [you can't validate a single element of an array](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/glMYogK6gKk). Instead run validation on entire array and loop through it's values if needed.

Assuming `valid` is a function to validate a single element:

```coffeescript
definitions:
  english: 
    type      : [ String ]
    validate  :

      validator : (values) ->
        for value in values
          if not (valid value) then return false
        return true

      msg       : "At least one not valid"

  ]
```

By setting `required` flag I assume you wanted to make sure at least one element is in the array. To achive that, add another validate object like that:

```coffeescript
definitions:
  english: 
    type      : [ String ]
    validate  : [  
      validator : (values) -> values.length # 0 is a falsy value
      msg       : "At least one required"                
    ,
      validator : (values) ->
        for value in values
          if not (valid value) then return false
        return true
      msg       : "At least one not valid"
    ]
  ]
```